# FileWriter creates a file, but leaves it empty?

Tags: java, filewriter

I'm trying to use a **fileWriter*** to write text data to a text file, but the program creates the file with nothing in it... *I'd be fine with using other methods to write to a file, but none of them have worked for me... (It doesn't much matter to me *how* it gets done, so long as it works.)

I've added a snippet of my code below, the only important method in class CommandInterpretation.

```
    private static FileWriter writer; //initialized outside so as to last through multiple calls

//Main area, processes the input fed from the user.
public String processInput(String theInput) {
    try {
        String theOutput = null;
        writer = new FileWriter("Default.txt",true); //initialized to a random file, otherwise it doesn't compile as I may have tried to close it without initializing
        if (state == ORIGINAL) {
            theOutput = "Hello, Master.";
            state = PROCESSCMDS;
        } else if (state == PROCESSCMDS) {
            if (theInput.split(" ")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("save")) {
                writer.close();
                writer = new FileWriter(theInput.split(" ")[1],true);
                theOutput = "Created new file: what's in it? (eof to end)";
                state = WRITEFILE;
            } else if (theInput.split(" ")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("run")) {
                Runtime.getRuntime().exec("cmd /c start " + theInput.split(" ")[1]);
                theOutput = "Successfully executed " + theInput.split(" ")[1] + ".";
            } else if (theInput.split(" ")[0].equalsIgnoreCase("close")) {
                state = ENDPROCESS;
            }
        } else if (state == WRITEFILE) { //file line input
            if (theInput.equalsIgnoreCase("eof")) {
                writer.close();
                theOutput = "File closed.";
                state = PROCESSCMDS;
            } else {
                writer.write(theInput);
                writer.write("\r\n");
                theOutput = "Next Line: ";
            }
        } 
        if (state == ENDPROCESS) {
            theOutput = "Bye.";
            state = ORIGINAL;
        }
        if (theOutput == null)
            return "Command not recognized.";
        return theOutput;
    } catch (Exception e) {return "Something went wrong: " + e.getMessage();}
}
```

I tried looking around for an answer, but all I could find were a bunch of similar questions where people forgot to close() their file.

In my output, I see "File Closed.", so it must've run that portion of the code... and even so the file remains empty...

In summary, the issue is that the fileWriter is creating a file with the name I assign it, but the file is empty. Default.txt is created and empty, which is fine, but theInput.split(" ")[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWQMl.png) is created and empty as well. I appreciate any help you guys can provide me!

Thanks in advance.

Some example calls, as requested, using the simple method below:

```
import java.util.*;

public class test
{
    //tester for other program
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Starting...");
        CommandInterpretation ci = new CommandInterpretation();
        Scanner in = new Scanner( System.in );
        while (true)
            System.out.println(ci.processInput(in.nextLine()));
        }
}
```

...and [here's the output.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WWQMl.png)

Comment: refactor your code, you are creating more than one writer but no closing all of them. Which file is empty `Default.txt` or `theInput.split(" ")[1]`? Post some sample inputs

Comment: Use some id, but breakpoints and debug it. Also while asking question in SO post always http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: My bad, I suppose the test data may not have made much sense without an explanation of what CommandInterpretation was. I attempted to debug it with println's like "Next Line:" and such, not sure how to further debug. (that's why I came here xP). all code necessary for reproducing the error should be included.